# How to drive variable power (up to 1500w) to a grill heating element from a 120V wall socket

Tags: power-supply

have a heating element like the following:

[[image: heating element]]

which is rated to 1500W. I need to be able to drive up to 1500W of power to it, but potentially less. I will be plugging it into a 120V wall outlet.

I am wondering what kind of components I need to make this happen, cheaper and more DIY is better :)

Thank you for your opinion

Comment: Your prioritisation of "cheaper" over, for example, safety is a cause for concern. What training and experience do you have in working with mains voltages and what is your understanding of earthing / grounding requirements?

Comment: Is the element rated to operate on 120 V?  I'd expect an oven element like that to be designed for 240 V operation.

Comment: Voting to close because this question is opinion-based.  If you _edit your question_ with a proposed method and ask if it'll work, then the question will fit within the electronics.stackexchange.com guidelines.  (Or find a forum that encourages open-ended discussions).

Comment: Triac, dynistor, capacitor,, variable resistor, heat sink

Comment: 1 MCU and 1 zero-cross SSR should be the simplest. make your own PWM at half main's frequency by toggling high/low on the pin driving the SSR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making it draw less power, the normal thing to do is to make it run less than 100% of the time (PWM). A device that could continuously regulate the power through a heating element like that would be big, expensive, and prone to getting very hot itself. Switches (i.e. relays or solid state relays) are simple, affordable, and low-loss. If you want 500W of average power, you simply run your 1500W element with a 33% duty cycle. Since the element heats up and cools down fairly slowly, the switching time can also be slow, if that suits your choice of switching technology.